# What condition should be applyed to child component in order to render conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component that recieve a child and pass it to MUI `Menu`

```
export default function MyMenu({children}){
    return(
        <Menu>
            {children ? children : <MenuItem disabled></MenuItem>}
          </Menu>
    );
}
```

children has a type `children: ReactNode;`

and I pass to it menu items like so

```
<MyMenu>
{condition && (<MenuItem></MenuItem>)}
{condition2 && (<MenuItem></MenuItem>)}
</MyMenu>
```

I want that when all conditions are false to render a disabled menu item
The problem is that `child` is never null if I pass children as above. And because of that disabled menu item is never rendered
If all conditions are false then `child` is an array of false. But in the code I can't treat `child` prop as an array to check whether it contains only false values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [React.Children.toArray](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray):

```
const MyMenu = ({ children }) => {
  const hasChildren = React.Children.toArray(children)
    .filter(Boolean)
    .length > 0
  
  if (hasChildren) {
    return children
  }

  return <MenuItem disabled />
}
```

Note: Not tested.

Comment: nice approach, it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-lab-n791v?file=/src/labPages/Experiments/test_files/8/index.jsx

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `React.Children.count(children)` and try :

```
export default function MyMenu({children}){
    
   return(
        <Menu>
            {React.Children.count(children) ? children : <MenuItem disabled></MenuItem>}
          </Menu>
    );
}
```

Comment: No it always result to 2. Even if I pass child like this `{condition ? (<MenuItem></MenuItem>) : null}` It gives me an array of nulls

Comment: THen can you not check `{children.length ? children :  <MenuItem disabled></MenuItem>}` ?

Comment: `children` has a type `ReactNode`. It does not have a length method

Answer (score 0):

you can filter the `children` array (if it wasn't an array it will be a primitive value) to remove the nil values from it, here is an example:

```js
const MyMenu = ({ children }) => {
  const tmp = Array.isArray(children)
    ? compact(children)
    : isNil(children)
    ? undefined
    : children;

  return <div>{tmp || tmp.length > 0 ? tmp : "DISABLED"}</div>;
};
```

sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-lab-n791v?file=/src/labPages/Experiments/test_files/8/index.jsx